# IF Formula to auto populate cost center name basis the cost center number in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, nested-if

So I have a bunch of cost centers in column A. Basis the cost center number, I want the column B to be filled with cost center name automatically in excel. For example if the cost center number = 101 Or 105 Or 108 then the name in the Column B should be auto filled as "operations". if the cost center number is = 102, or 106 or 107, then the cost center name should be "marketing" and so on..

I tried writing below formula to achieve at least one condition but it is not working.

`=IF(OR($A$2=101,$A$2=105,$A$2=108,"Operations",""))`

Please help with an IF statement that combines And and OR conditions to fill the names basis the numbers in column A

[image: | Cost Center Number | Cost Center Name | | ___________________| _________________| | 101]

Comment: Try: `=IFS(OR({101,105,108}=A2),"Operations",OR({102,106,107}=A2),"Marketing")` or `=IF(OR(A2=101,A2=105,A2=108),"Operations",IF(OR(A2=102,A2=106,A2=107),"Marketing",""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplace the true and false result into `OR`, simply move them out like so and it will work.

```
=IF(OR($A$2=101,$A$2=105,$A$2=108),"Operations","")
```

If you want to meet other criteria, you can add simply use `IFS` and `OR`.

```
=IFS(OR(A2=101,A2=105,A2=108), "Operation", OR(A2=102,A2=106,A2=107), "Marketing")
```

But in this case, your formular will become longer with more criteria. Hence, I would suggest using `VLOOKUP`. You need to create a lookup table in the sheet that represent the key and value:

```
+---+----------+
|key|value     |
+---+----------+
|101|Operations|
|102|Marketing |
... and so on
```

then use this formula to lookup the value

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'lookup table'!A:B,2)
```

here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GDqV_UZGmtIT01bAJgP4PQgPzvU41QbxyLyDO2YhW3U/edit